# How to solve the problem of loading Fortran projects in Microsoft Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: load, project, visual-studio-2022, intel-fortran

After installing the version 17.2, I can no longer load my Fortran projects into Microsoft Visual studio.
When I open the .sln file, I get the two following errors.

[image]

[image]

It seems that the problem is due to the inability to load the package: 'CompatibilityToolPackage' correctly.

[My ActivityLog.xml file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C_YosPFZkv2Gd88qYbvB430EqgDuwZ_3/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this message from Intel about the problem:

https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/Do-not-upgrade-VS-2022-to-version-v17-2-It-breaks-all/m-p/1382358

Basically, Visual Studio 17.2 does not work with Intel Fortran. There is no workaround. You have to back install to a previous version of Visual Studio. The document gives instructions on how, and I have copied and pasted them here:

1. Uninstall all Intel oneAPI components
2. Uninstall Visual Studio 2022 v17.2 completely
3. Find and download Visual Studio 2022 v17.1 or older.  Links provided below
4. Install Visual Studio 2022 v17.1 or older.  See System Requirements, Visual
   Studio
5. Install Intel oneAPI Toolkit(s) or Intel Fortran component

Comment: Hi Ron, I followed the discussion in your link, I'd want to install the  VS 17.0 community edition release but I can't find the link to download it. Can you help me?

Comment: There was a link at the bottom at the bottom of the attached page that takes you to historical Fortran. I pasted it here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/

Comment: I didn't use those files. I used an old file of Visual Studio 2019 someone had at my work. I hope this works for you.

Comment: Thank you @Ron L. I downloaded the Pro version that is a trial version. In three months I will use VS 2019 if the problem is still there.

Answer (score 1):

The following steps work for newest versions of Visual Studio and Intel oneAPI as of now (Jan 16 2023).

Uninstall:

- All oneAPI packages (HPC, Base)
- Visual Studio

Install (64-bit):

- Visual Studio Community 2022 (v17.4.4)
- Intel oneAPI Base Toolkit (v2023.0.0)
- Intel oneAPI HPC Toolkit (v2023.0.0)

Install (32-bit):

- Visual Studio Community 2022 (v17.4.4)
- [Intel oneAPI Math Kernel Library for Windows](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/tool/oneapi-standalone-components.html) (v2023.0.0)
- [Intel Integrated Performance Primitives for Windows](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/tool/oneapi-standalone-components.html) (v2021.7.0)
- Intel oneAPI Base Toolkit 32-bit (v2023.0.0)
- Intel oneAPI Base Toolkit (v2023.0.0)
- Intel oneAPI HPC Toolkit (v2023.0.0)

To open old Fortran solutions (especially when it is cloned or copied to a new PC):

- Open the folder (folder A) that contain the solution file (.sln)
- In the File Explorer, open View/Options/View/Show hidden files, folders, or drives
- Delete the hidden .vs folder within folder A
- Run the solution file, and it works now!

If not, VS will show that the Fortran project is incompatible.